# Dynamically adding and deleting entry boxes Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to make a gui that gives a user a range of input boxes depending on what type of statistical distribution they selected. This will be used in a calculation later in the script. Each statistical distribution requires a different amount of variables (hence the need to dynamically populate a number of input boxes). Right now my code sort of works. The problem is that if you select a distribution that gives you 5 input boxes and then switch the distribution to one that only requires 3, the 5 boxes from the previous selection are still there. For this script a truncated normal distribution is supposed to have 3 variables, a normal distribution is supposed to have 5 variables and a discrete distribution is supposed to have 4 variables.

I thought that if I created a dummy input box and then removed it at the end of the if statement, it would end up deleting the box(s) that I dont need. This doesnt appear to have worked though.

Below is the code that I have so far. I feel like I am almost there and am just missing something. I would greatly appreciate any advice. Again the goal is to populate just the right ammount of input boxes for each statistical distribution selection and then to be able to change that selection dynamically and have the number of input boxes change accordingly.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.ttk import *

master = tk.Tk()
master.title("Gas Calculator")
v = tk.IntVar()
combo = Combobox(master)

def callbackARS(eventObject):
    ARDist=(comboARS.get())


    if ARDist == "Truncated Normal":
        a1 = tk.Entry(master)
        a2 = tk.Entry(master)
        a3 = tk.Entry(master)
        #attempt to create a dummy input box that isnt needed and then delete it at the end of the code
        a4 = tk.Entry(master)
        a1.grid(row=3, column=4)
        a2.grid(row=3, column=5)
        a3.grid(row=3, column=6)
        a4.grid(row=3, column=7)
        tk.Label(master, text="Variable", padx=20, width=10, bg = "light blue").grid(row=2,column=4)
        tk.Label(master, text="Area", padx=20, width=10, bg = "light blue").grid(row=2,column=5)
        tk.Label(master, text="Thickness", padx=20, width=10, bg = "light blue").grid(row=2,column=6)
        tk.Label(master, text="", padx=20, width=10, bg = "light blue").grid(row=2,column=7)
        #attempt to create a dummy input box that isnt needed and then delete it at the end of the code
        a4.grid_remove()

    if ARDist == "Normal":
        b1 = tk.Entry(master)
        b2 = tk.Entry(master)
        b3 = tk.Entry(master)
        b4 = tk.Entry(master)
        b5 = tk.Entry(master)
        b1.grid(row=3, column=4)
        b2.grid(row=3, column=5)
        b3.grid(row=3, column=6)
        b4.grid(row=3, column=7)
        b5.grid(row=3, column=8)
        tk.Label(master, text="a", padx=20, width=10, bg = "light blue").grid(row=2,column=4)
        tk.Label(master, text="Aa", padx=20, width=10, bg = "light blue").grid(row=2,column=5)
        tk.Label(master, text="aaa", padx=20, width=10, bg = "light blue").grid(row=2,column=6)
        tk.Label(master, text="aaaa", padx=20, width=10, bg = "light blue").grid(row=2,column=7)

    if ARDist == "Discrete":
        a1 = tk.Entry(master)
        a2 = tk.Entry(master)
        a3 = tk.Entry(master)
        a4 = tk.Entry(master)
        a1.grid(row=3, column=4)
        a2.grid(row=3, column=5)
        a3.grid(row=3, column=6)
        a4.grid(row=3, column=7)

#Distribution selction
comboARS = Combobox(master)
comboARS['values']= ("Truncated Normal", "Normal", "Discrete")
comboARS.current(0) #set the selected item
comboARS.grid(row=3, column=3)
comboARS.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", callbackARS)
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anywhere in your code where you delete old entry widgets before creating new ones. Every time your function is called you create more widgets.

Comment: I ran your code and selected "Truncated Normal."  I saw four Labels in row 2, the fourth being blank.  There were three Entries in row 3, exactly what you would expect after the call to grid_remove().  What is the problem?  BTW, grid_remove doesn't delete the object, it just makes it invisible.

Comment: *For this script a truncated normal distribution is supposed to have 3 variables*: then why in your code there are 4 entries and 4 labels for this case?

Comment: @PaulCornelius try to switch between the variables and you will see that once you select the selection with the most number of input boxes and then try to switch to one with less input boxes, it does not delete the unnecesarry input boxes

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ that was my attempt to try and trick python into doing what I want it to do. I thought that if I gave it a dummy input box it would end up deleting the ones I dont need whenever I switch between selections. It obviously didnt work.

Comment: I see what will happen if I try to switch between variables.  The point of my comment is that the method grid_remove() does exactly what it's supposed to do.  That is the functionality you need, but you seem to think it doesn't work.  What is missing from your program logic is a means of keeping track of all the Entries and Labels.  You could create five of each the first time the button is clicked, and save them in a list (or two lists).  Then you grid them or remove them as needed, depending on how many parameters you have.

Answer (score 0):

if you create a single set of labels and entry fields in a frame you can easily manipulate their properties and visibility. Combinations of the grid_remove() and winfo_children() methods are pretty useful.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

master = tk.Tk()
my_frame = tk.Frame()
my_frame.grid(row=0, column=1)
# create one set of widgets in a frame
for num in range(1, 6):
    tk.Label(master=my_frame).grid(row=0,column=num)
    tk.Entry(master=my_frame).grid(row=1, column=num)
def detect_selection(eventobject):
    the_selection = eventobject.widget.get()
    # hide all widgets
    for item in my_frame.winfo_children():
        item.grid_remove()
    show_idx__wigets = 6
    if the_selection == '3':
        change_labeltext(('a', 'b', 'c'), 6)
    if the_selection == '4':
        show_idx__wigets = 8
        change_labeltext(('d', 'e', 'f', 'g'), 8)
    if the_selection == '5':
        show_idx__wigets = 10
        change_labeltext(('h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l'), 10)
    # reveal only desired number of widgets
    show_widgets(show_idx__wigets)

def show_widgets(upto_widgetposition):
    for item in my_frame.winfo_children()[:upto_widgetposition]:
        item.grid()
def change_labeltext(labeltext, upto_widgetposition):
    for txt, item in zip(
        labeltext, my_frame.winfo_children()[:upto_widgetposition:2]):
        item['text'] = txt    
combo = ttk.Combobox(master,
                     values=(3,4,5))
combo.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='s')
combo.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', detect_selection)

master.mainloop()
```